# How to create a numpy record array from C

Tags: python, c, numpy

On the Python side, I can create new numpy record arrays as follows:

```
numpy.zeros((3,), dtype=[('a', 'i4'), ('b', 'U5')])
```

How do I do the same from a C program?  I suppose I have to call `PyArray_SimpleNewFromDescr(nd, dims, descr)`, but how do I construct a `PyArray_Descr` that is appropriate for passing as the third argument to `PyArray_SimpleNewFromDescr`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `PyArray_DescrConverter`.  Here's an example:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int dims[] = { 2, 3 };
     PyObject *op, *array;
     PyArray_Descr *descr;

     Py_Initialize();
     import_array();
     op = Py_BuildValue("[(s, s), (s, s)]", "a", "i4", "b", "U5");
     PyArray_DescrConverter(op, &descr);
     Py_DECREF(op);
     array = PyArray_SimpleNewFromDescr(2, dims, descr);
     PyObject_Print(array, stdout, 0);
     printf("\n");
     Py_DECREF(array);
     return 0;
}
```

Thanks to [Adam Rosenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9530/adam-rosenfield) for pointing to Section 13.3.10 of the [Guide to NumPy](https://web.archive.org/web/20090117100715/http://numpy.scipy.org:80/numpybook.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

See the [Guide to NumPy](http://csc.ucdavis.edu/~chaos/courses/nlp/Software/NumPyBook.pdf), section 13.3.10.  There's lots of different ways to make a descriptor, although it's not nearly as easy as writing `[('a', 'i4'), ('b', 'U5')]`.

Comment: Thanks, the Guide mentioned `PyArray_DescrConverter`, which works.  I've posted an example as a separate answer, as it doesn't fit in a comment.

Comment: @JoelVroom: I don't know what happened to the original link, but I was able to find another link to the same document easily enough.